# Facet barplot by list in r using ggplot2

Tags: r

Sorry about my limited knowledge, I am a bit of a beginner.

I am trying to do a project for a class, where we have to create a data visualization, and I found a data frame I want to use (`starwars` in the `dplyr` package), but I am having a few issues. I want to facet the data based on items in a list. Basically I want to see what is the most common homeworld for characters in a film. This is the command I was trying to run.

```
library('dplyr')
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(starwars,aes(x=homeworld)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~films)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is waht you are looking for.

1. As the films in which each character apperared are stored in a list column you first have to `tidyr::unnest` that column.
2. To get a nice plot in the end it's best to compute the counts manually
3. This way we can make use of `reorder_within` and `scale_xxx_reordered` from tidytext which gives us ordered plots per facet.
4. Also, it's best to put homeworld on the y-axis. Additonally I dropped all obs with missing homeworlds.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

starwars %>% 
  unnest(films) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(homeworld)) %>%
  count(homeworld, films) %>% 
  mutate(homeworld = tidytext::reorder_within(homeworld, n, films)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = homeworld)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~films, scales = "free_y") +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered()
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Nice that the R section is noob-friendly, too.